# graph combine labels for each column and each row

Tags: graph, label, stata

I am using `graph combine` to combine a number of plots.  How can I label each column and each row? In my case, each column graphs a different variable and each row uses a different sample. I would prefer not to have a label for each graph individually as this makes it a lot more cluttered.

An example of what I would like can be found [here](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/vouchermapsBAYES2000.png).

I have looked in the documentation, but did not find a solution. I did find this [post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/396778-common-x-and-ytitle-for-combined-graphs) on Statalist, but the solution there produces just one common title for the entire axis, not separate ones by columns/rows.

Is it possible to manually add text in the spirit of `text(x y "text...")` to `graph combine`?

Here is an example:

```
sysuse uslifeexp, clear

graph drop _all
line le_male year if year<=1950, ytitle("") name(male1900)

line le_female year if year<=1950, ytitle("") name(female1900)

line le_male year if year>1950, ytitle("") name(male1951)

line le_female year if year>1950, ytitle("") name(female1951)

graph combine male1900 female1900 male1951 female1951, rows(2) cols(2)
```

I would like to label it as follows (with more space on the row labels so that it doesn't spill into the graph; importantly, the label should not be part of the individual small graph, but put onto the combined set of graphs produced by `graph combine`):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse uslifeexp, clear

line le_male year if year<=1950, xlabel("") xtitle("") ytitle("1900-1950", ///
                                 orientation(horizontal)) title(MALE) name(male1900)

line le_female year if year<=1950, xlabel("") xtitle("") ytitle("") ///
                                   title(FEMALE) name(female1900)

line le_male year if year>1950, xlabel("") xtitle("") ytitle("1951-1999", ///
                                orientation(horizontal)) name(male1951)

line le_female year if year>1950, xlabel("") xtitle("") ytitle("") name(female1951)

graph combine male1900 female1900 male1951 female1951, rows(2) cols(2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to restructure the data, so that the graph emerges from a call that includes the `by()` option. The order of the panels is naturally at choice. Once you have the graph, you can edit e.g. graph subtitles.

```
sysuse uslifeexp, clear

keep le_male le_female year 

gen period = year > 1950
label define period 0 "1901-1950" 1 "1951-1999" 
label val period period 

reshape long le_ , i(year) j(gender) string 

egen panel = group(gender period), label 

label var le "Life expectancy (years)"

set scheme s1color 

line le_ year, by(panel, note("") xrescale imargin(medsmall)) ///
yla(, ang(h)) xlabel(#5) xtitle("")
```

[image]

See also `twby` from SSC.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. This is a great solution.